# C++ store number of times main is called

Tags: c++, static, program-entry-point

How do I have main() remember the value of a variable each time it is called?

i.e. if I run this program the first time I want `mainCallCounter = 0`, but when I is called again I want it to increase the counter

```
#include <iostream>   
using namespace std;

static int mainCallCounter = 0;

void outputMainCallCount()
{
   cout << "Main was called" << mainCallCounter << "times." << endl;

}

int main()
{

    outputMainCallCount();
    mainCallCounter++;

return 0;
```

Comment: Store the number in a file. Get the program to read it in?

Comment: Persist the number to disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All variables declared in C++ expire when the program ends.  If you want to persistently remember how many times the program has been run, you will need to store that data in an external file and update it whenever you run the program.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int numTimesRun() {
    std::ifstream input("counter.txt"); // assuming it exists
    int numTimesRun;
    input >> numTimesRun;
    return numTimesRun;
}

void updateCounter() {
    int counter = numTimesRun();
    std::ofstream output("counter.txt");
    output << counter;
}

int main() {
    int timesRun = numTimesRun();
    updateCounter();

    /* ... */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Main is the entry point for your program.  Main is called once (normally) and, when it exits, your program is torn down and cleaned up.

Obviously this means a local variable will be insufficient. You need some sort of external storage which persists longer than your application, i.e., the file system.

Comment: `main` is called once, period, in C++.

Comment: @CarlNorum: Is that right? `int main() { main(); }`

Comment: That's forbidden by the C++ standard.  "The function `main` shall not be used within a program."

Comment: @CarlNorum: Doesn't mean it didn't happen.

Comment: Discussing potential outcomes of undefined behaviour is hardly relevant.

Comment: I was just trying to clarify that in C++ you can't call it at all.  In a C program it's certainly possible (and allowed).  You *can't* do it in C++ and expect any particular semantics.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Each run of a program is independent.  You will need to save `mainCallCounter` somewhere and re-read it the next time the application launches.  Writing it into a file is one option, another might be something like the Windows registry or Mac OS X defaults system, etc.